# Hot loading .jar files: random FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, plugins, reflection, jar, filenotfoundexception

I have a `PluginManager` class that watches a `./plugins` directory for file creation using a `WatchService`and then utilizes a static method `loadPlugin(File)` from a `PluginLoader` class to load newly added jars at runtime. All jars in the folder are also loaded and started at application start up, in that case everything goes well, even with a bunch of plugins.
But when I drop the plugins into the folder one by one I get a weird behavior:

- the first jar is loaded fine in 98% of the time
- the second only in about 5%
- the third only in a very rare case, but it happens

What I get is this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\plugins\test2.jar (Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:34)
at PluginManager$WatchQueueReader.run(PluginManager.java:118)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "FileWatcher" java.lang.NullPointerException
at PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:41)
at PluginManager$WatchQueueReader.run(PluginManager.java:118)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It is saying that the file is used in another process.

**PluginLoader:**

```
public static BasePlugin loadPlugin(File pluginJar) {
    Attributes attrib = null;
    JarFile file = null;
    try {
        file = new JarFile(pluginJar);
        Manifest manifest = file.getManifest();
        attrib = manifest.getMainAttributes();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String main = attrib.getValue(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS);
    String name = attrib.getValue("Plugin-Name");

    if (main == null || name == null) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid manifest: " + pluginJar.getName());
        return null;
    }

    URLClassLoader loader = null;
    try {
        loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { pluginJar.toURI().toURL() }, PluginLoader.class.getClassLoader());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    Class<?> cl = null;
    try {
        cl = Class.forName(main, true, loader);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            loader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        Class<? extends BasePlugin> c = cl.asSubclass(BasePlugin.class);
        Constructor<? extends BasePlugin> ctr = c.getConstructor(String.class, SystemManager.class);
        return ctr.newInstance(name, this.sm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**WatchService inside PluginManager:**

```
    private static class WatchQueueReader implements Runnable {

    private WatchService watcher;
    private PluginManager pm;

    public WatchQueueReader(PluginManager pm, WatchService watcher) {
        this.pm = pm;
        this.watcher = watcher;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            WatchKey key = watcher.take();
            while (key != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    switch (event.kind().toString()) {
                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                        Path dir = (Path) key.watchable();
                        Path fullPath = dir.resolve(event.context().toString());
                        BasePlugin plugin = PluginLoader.loadPlugin(fullPath.toFile());
                        if (plugin != null) {
                            this.pm.startPlugin(plugin);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                        break;
                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                        this.pm.stopPlugin(event.context().toString()); // TODO wrong name (.jar)
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
                key.reset();
                key = watcher.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BasePlugin is an abstract class that plugins extend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is still being copied, the WatchService simply finds it too soon.

In fact, it will report the file as existing as soon as it['s inode] is created, but not yet filled with information (the bytes, you know).

My first tip is that if you encounter this exception, wait a few seconds and try again. Just after like 10-30 seconds of futile attempts you can give up, as it have been deleted maybe. But this part needs fine tuning, as maybe the copy operation is slow.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Maybe it's possible to wait for the ENTRY_MODIFY after the ENTRY_CREATE?

Comment: I'm not sure. The docs says: "When an event is reported to indicate that a file in a watched directory has been modified then there is no guarantee that the program (or programs) that have modified the file have completed."